Solana Verification Error
I'm trying to run the solana-verify CLI command on my github repo. I'm getting a docker error. I believe I'm missing something on Docker connection because even when i ping registry-1.docker.io it fails, and need your help with it.
I developed the program on Solana Playground IDE.
Below is the error I'm getting while running the command:
solana-verify verify-from-repo https://github.com/JNGLToken/jngl-random-verify.git --program-id yiceQsjcTNcp92V7isaYrmvRi6CvvA21HR5gA3TrS47
Below is the error:
Mounting path: /tmp/solana-verify/b6408892-ca87-4d9f-a37c-37be0a8092af/jngl-random-verify.git Found docker image for Solana version 1.18.26 Unable to find image 'solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build@sha256:f3d3a4adaa8008644fc4535373c6818275c7e35a0b07660890b4a95ef434221e' locally docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build/manifests/sha256:f3d3a4adaa8008644fc4535373c6818275c7e35a0b07660890b4a95ef434221e": read tcp 172.29.135.191:49488->54.198.86.24:443: read: connection reset by peer. See 'docker run --help'. Removing temporary directory /tmp/solana-verify/b6408892-ca87-4d9f-a37c-37be0a8092af Removed temporary directory /tmp/solana-verify/b6408892-ca87-4d9f-a37c-37be0a8092af Error: Error verifying program. Err(Failed to parse output)

Works for me. Which version of solana-verify are you using? : Found docker image for Solana version 1.18.26
Unable to find image 'solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build@sha256:f3d3a4adaa8008644fc4535373c6818275c7e35a0b07660890b4a95ef434221e' locally
docker.io/solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build@sha256:f3d3a4adaa8008644fc4535373c6818275c7e35a0b07660890b4a95ef434221e: Pulling from solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build

Hi @JonasH. Thank you for your reply.
I'm using solana-verify 0.3.1 latest version
it seems a docker related error.
Also, does ping registry-1.docker.io works at your machine? Do you have any changes related to docker in your /etc/hosts file? can you show me what's under sudo nano /etc/hosts that is related to docker?
Thank you for your help

I dont have any special entries there. Only localhost. Maybe try reinstall docker? The ping also times out for me
